# How to implement heap with recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, heap

I've been trying to implement heap(this one is max heap) with recursion in ***"C"*** language but the problem is I'm not getting an appropriate output from it, In the code below the `insert` function takes the input data and the address of the array which is created for heap as an argument and then checks if the data is greater than it's parent node or not,and if the data turns out to be greater then it replaces the smaller value which is placed on the index of the parent with the higher value which is placed on the index of the data and it repeats the process until it satisfies the property of max heap or until it reaches the root, Here the index of parent is represented as `heap[i-1]/2` and the index of the newly added data is just ***"i"*** i.e `heap[i]` 
Suppose I input *20* and after that if I input a larger value like *30* then the output should be *30* 
*20* but instead I only get the output as *30* and If decide to add another larger value (say 40) then it replaces the *30* and the output becomes only *40*.
here's the code ->

```
int i = 0;
void insert(int heap[],int data)
{
    int j = 0;
    if(i == 0)
        {
            heap[i] = data;
        }
        else if(heap[(i-1)/2] < data)
        {
            heap[i] = heap[(i-1)/2];
            i = (i-1)/2;
            insert(heap,data);

        }
}
void display(int heap[],int size)
{
    system("cls");
    for(int i=0,j=1;i<size;i++,j++)
    {
        printf("%d.) %d\n",j,heap[i]);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int heap[5],men,data,c;
    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");

        printf("1.) Insert\n");
        printf("2.) Display\n");
        printf("3.) exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d",&men);
        switch(men)
        {
            case 1 : printf("Enter data : ");
                     scanf("%d",&data);
                     heap[i] = data;
                     insert(heap,data);
                     i++;
                     printf("%d successfully added to heap!",data);
                     break;

            case 2 : display(heap,i);
                    break;

            case 3 : exit(0);
            break;

            default : printf("Invalid choice!");
                      while((c=fgetc(stdin))!='\n'){}
                      break;            
        }
        getch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't tag C++ for C questions. They are different languages.

Comment: You are using the same variable `i` for maintaining the heap and also keeping track of the size of your heap. You should separate those.

Comment: @valarMorghulis Yes! you are right I also just realized the same thing a few moments ago thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `insert` method is that you never add anything to the array, except when `i==0`.

The algorithm for adding an item to a min heap is:

```
Add new item to the end of the array.
While the new item is smaller than its parent
    swap new item with parent item
```

Translated to pseudo code and optimized a bit, that becomes:

```
count = count + 1
i = count - 1
parent = (i-1)/2
while (data < a[parent])
    a[i] = a[parent])
    i = parent
    parent = (i-1)/2
a[i] = data
```

The recursive version is pretty much the same.

Your code never increases the count, so the heap can't grow.

Comment: Hi. .Jim thanks for your answer,so actually before you published your answer I was also analyzing my code and found out the same thing that you pointed out the only difference is that the code in question is for max heap.